# How exactly does the "Strange Part: Domination Kills" count?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a couple weapons with the domination kills strange part, however haven't fully understood the *exact* circumstances in which those kills increase. The description of the part states:

> Adding this Strange Part to a Strange-quality weapon will enable it to track the number of enemies you dominate by killing them with that weapon.

Does it only increase on a kill where I specifically dominated someone with that weapon? Or, can the domination count increase with either of the following circumstances?

- Increases on the actual domination, and any subsequent kills thereafter on that player until they exact revenge
- Increases if the actual domination just so happened to take place on an assist

Comment: I believe it's the former, but I don't have the part to check

Comment: I've gotten name upgrade notifications after kills rather than after domination messages. (I'm a fairly mediocre player; I *rarely* get a domination to begin with but my basic flamethrower's got an impressive adjective by now)

Comment: "Increases if the actual domination just so happened to take place on an assist" Considering that the item description specifically states that it tracks "the number of enemies you dominate by killing them with that weapon", I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only count when you "dominate" an enemy for the first time.  When you hear that familiar sound that indicates a [domination](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Domination), it should increase your counter by 1.

Subsequent kills on a dominated enemy will not increase the counter for the part.  However, that same player can remove the domination by:

- switching teams, then switching back
- leaving the server, then rejoining
- getting revenge

If any of these three things happen, the previous "domination" will be wiped, allowing you to dominate the player again, if you wish.

Comment: Does it count even if you dominate them without killing them, just getting the assist domination? (Like if you're a medic.)

Comment: Nope There's a reason why the S. Part Domination Kills cannot be applied to S. Mediguns